# count row in table with identical value of two column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is my table structure and data...

```
id   receiver   caller category   playfilename
1    4564165    42444    4        skdjfls.wav
2    4444444    42444    2        dfkjsanf.wav
3    4444444    42444    2        kldsfjas.wav
4    4845455    42444    3        dsklfjal.wav
5    4542122    42444    2        dfssadfs.wav
6    4535656    42444    2        dsfjklsaj.wav
```

Here, I want to count the number of rows which have same receiver and category column data. For example in above table return one extra select column with total count of 2 which have 4444444 receiver and category 2. similarly return other rows that match value on receiver and caller to another row with count column as something like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT receiver, caller, category, playfilename, count from tbl_record .... ...
```

I have no ideas how can I do it. IS there any function in sql server to solve this problem or i have use something like stored procedure

Comment: Can you add what output format to want to display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    receiver, caller, category, playfilename,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY receiver, category) AS CountPerReceivercategoryGroup
from tbl_record
```